# Adding Icon on Wordpress Header Menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, icons

I want to add the cart icon instead of the wording and the count in wordpress header menu. like this [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FnuA.png)

So I inserted the below code to functions.php in my theme folder.

```html
add_filter( 'menu_image_default_sizes', function($sizes){
  
  // remove the default 36x36 size
  unset($sizes['menu-36x36']);
  
  // add a new size
  $sizes['menu-50x50'] = array(50,50);
  
  // return $sizes (required)
  return $sizes;
  
});
```

But still im not able to insert icons/images to the header menu. Any solution?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This code only changes the default sizes - `menu_image_default_sizes`. You need to show us your code for where you are trying to change the menu itself. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take a look how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see what you needto give us so we can understand what you are doing and be able to help.

Comment: ok i will see to it